# parameters property in taurus syntax

Tags: taurus

Can someone please explain what the property `parameters` means in this taurus syntax? I tried to find documentation for the syntax, but I couldn't find a reference to it.

```
- url: ${endpoints}
        label: 1359_CheckADCLientDeletion
        headers:
          Authorization: Bearer ${access_token}
          Content-Type: "application/json"
        assert-httpcode:
          - 200
          - 202
        jsr223:
          - langauge: groovy
            execute: before
            script-text: |
              vars.put("searchName", "test")
              vars.put("listUrl", "${endpoints}")
          - language: groovy
            execute: after
            script-file: jsr223/checkForDeletedADClient.groovy
            parameters: check_ad_client_deletion
          - langauge: groovy
            execute: after
            script-file: jsr223/logger.groovy
            parameters: check_ad_client_deletion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not 100% JMeter, it's syntax for [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool.

This `parameters` attribute is for [JSR223 Blocks](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JSR223-Blocks) looking at `execute: after` it will generate a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and put `check_ad_client_deletion` into its "Parameters" section:

[image: check_ad_client_deletion]

You can always execute `bzt your_test.yml -gui` command and it will launch JMeter GUI so you could inspect the resulting JMeter script normally.

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

Comment: I updated the question  title. I apologize  for  that. I am still new to testing. Thank you for your answer!